# TensorFlow KeyError: 'RegexReplace' when predict on DNNClassifier using tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, centos7

I am trying to restore an estimator and predict on it.

**System Config** : 
CentOS 7 - x64 - CPU
tensorflow == 1.5

This is how I saved the estimator DNNClassifier

```
 def serving_input_receiver_fn():
      inputs = {"embeddings": tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)}
      return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

 export_dir = estimator.export_savedmodel(
                 export_dir_base='models/run7',
                 serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

I reloaded it using **tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model** as follows

```
estimator = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model('model/1528805269/')
```

but, then I get the error **KeyError: 'RegexReplace'** on the above line

complete error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "app.py", line 38, in <module>
        load_model()
      File "app.py", line 21, in load_model
        estimator = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model('model/1528805269/')
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/predictor_factories.py", line 129, in from_saved_model
        graph=graph)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/saved_model_predictor.py", line 156, in __init__
        loader.load(self._session, tags.split(','), export_dir)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 216, in load
        saver = tf_saver.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def_to_load, **saver_kwargs)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1838, in import_meta_graph
        **kwargs)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
        producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 433, in import_graph_def
        _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
      File "/var/www/html/my_project/prj_v4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 211, in _RemoveDefaultAttrs
        op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'RegexReplace'
```

Any Suggestions what might be going wrong ?

Comment: RegexReplace wasn't in TensorFlow for 1.5, so I'm guessing you're saving the SavedModel in 1.6+ and using it in 1.5 (and the op doesn't exist in 1.5, thus the error).

Comment: Ah!... well I guess I am in a fix then.... I trained a model on google colab using some modules from tensorflow hub, which requires tf 1.7 >= , and my system has illegal instructions core dump problem, which won't allow tf version > 1.5... I had trained some models in tf 1.8 and ran in 1.5 with no issues...i guess this time it won't work...Thanks for the response..

Comment: Right, AVX instructions are used in the prepackaged builds. You could also build a more recent version from source without AVX.